# Host RestAPI inside IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a rather simple .NET WebApi application which I'm trying to host inside IIS. Followed all of the instructions from MS site about this.
here is the startup method for it.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

I configured the Application pool to not use any managed code but I'm getting still this error in logs

```
Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
```

I'm out of any ideas what can be wrong. 
Any suggestions?

Using .NET Core 2.2

Comment: do you have web.config?

Comment: Have you installed the .net core IIS hosting bundle? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.0-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Comment: yes, here is the web.config https://pastebin.com/Y9GNmGxw

Comment: yes, I did install the II hosting bundle.

Answer (score 9):

For `InProcess`, it uses `IISHttpServer`.

[image]

For your code, you are configuring `UseKestrel()` which uses `out-of-process`.

[image]

For solution, remove the `.UseKestrel()` line.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                //.UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

For more details, refer [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-description).

Answer (score 0):

I want to use `UseKestrel()`.
When I create .net core 2.0 or 2.1 project. I can use `UseKestrel()`
But If I create .net core 2.2 project I couldn't use `UseKestrel()`

I solved this problem like that

- Create new .net core 2.0 or 2.1 project. Then, you can upgrade .net core project to 2.2. It will work.

But it is not effective solution.