# Cannot run Asp Net Core API on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-express

I have an asp net core web api.

I can run it using **dotnet** command and it starts on https://localhost:5001/ (as it should) and everythings work fine.

But when i try to launch the api using **IIS Express** or using **IIS** it won't reach the page and gives me **error 500.30**:

[image: Browser error]

I have enabled **logs** in web.config and this is the result:

> Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: D:_APICore
>   Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Then i have an error in **Event viewer** too (it is in Italian):
[image: Event viewer error]

Last, this is the **Program.cs**:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Hope all these informations helps.
Thanks for any help.

### UPDATE

**StartUp.cs**:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        //Authorization settings
        services.AddCors(c => c.AddPolicy("Permissions", builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("Permissions"));
        });

        services.Configure<Values>(Configuration.GetSection("StoredValues"));

        //JWT setting configuration
        var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("StoredValues");
        var key = appSettings.GetValue(typeof(string), "JWTSecret").ToString();
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("Permissions");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

### UPDATE 2

I have found some older version of the program and these don't work either.

So now i'm wondering if this my problem or something else ???

Maybe some update ? I don't really know.

Comment: yes i have installed it

Comment: Yes this is what i did, but it gives me an error when i run it using IIS Express in Visual Studio too.

Comment: Which version of dotnet are you using? my app is 2.1 and I just need "WebHost                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();" to get it to work both in Kestrel and behind IIS. The default builder should be setting enough things for IIS hosting.

Comment: I'm using 2.2, other Uses are needed for run it in IIS and Kestrel and btw i  run the app using ISS Express yesterday and worked but now it does not work anymore

Comment: what do you mean? the path exists

Comment: I was expecting a backslash in it, but I can see it in the event viewer, so it is not the issue. Are you sure the user your app is running with has proper access to that path? Can you try to set up the identity of the app to a powerful user to check if that could an issue (https://medium.com/@premchandrasingh/hosting-asp-net-core-application-with-iis-1d08981191bf) ?

Comment: wait, HTTP 418's answer works but only for IIS but not for IIS Express, so i can assume the folder is not the problem (??)

Comment: it depends ... when you are using IIS Express, what is the user of the process? as opposed to which user is used by IIS. Try using VS2017 as admin to test.

Comment: mm i don't really know. Which user do you mean? the one i used to run VS?

Comment: how do you use "IIS Express"? Directly by debugging (pressing F5 or something like that) under Visual Studio? That is why I was suggesting changing the user of VS so that when VS launches the process to debug it could use another user.

Comment: Yes I run it with F5 in VS. And I use the same user for IIS and IIS E.

Comment: Just remove lines `.UseKestrel()` and `.UseIISIntegration()` and everything should work fine

Comment: @ElyasEsna No it still not working on IIS Express

Comment: Did you ever solve this???

Comment: @AX No, I didn't solve this, but make sure to have the last version of run time and check for ports availability

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to call `ConfigureKestrel` instead of `UseKestrel`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-to-use-kestrel-in-aspnet-core-apps

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
        {
            // Set properties and call methods on options
        });
```

Comment: And the problem isn't Kestrel but IIS

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `.UseKestrel()`

Reference/more info: [Host RestAPI inside IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688154/host-restapi-inside-iis) - follow the link provided in the answer. Be aware that you might need to configure further properties, which are described in that link.

Comment: So updated answer works on IIS but still not working on ISS Express

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini Is it the same error as mentioned in the original post, that you receive with IIS Express after removing `.UseKestrel()`? And can you please post your `ConfigureServices()` from your Startup-class in the original post? The reason can also be spelling errors in appsettings.json and/or launchsettings.json

Comment: I have added strtup file

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini my last guess is to put `app.UseMvc();` to the very last line of `Configure` method.

Comment: Does not seem to work... but in chrome i have ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error